# Mistura de inglês e português na home page https://pt.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: bug

## Em português (cortesia do Google Translate):

Acabei de olhar para a página inicial do Stack Overflow em Português] (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) no meu navegador e ver o texto de boas-vindas:

> Stack Overflow em Português is a question and answer site for programadores profissionais e entusiastas. It only takes a minute to sign up.

e:

> Explore our Questions

que parece uma estranha mistura de inglês e português, em vez de português puro.

[image: O que vejo no Firefox Quantum 69.0.1 em um Mac executando o macOS 10.14.6 Mojave]

Isso é apenas um problema porque meu navegador está configurado para funcionar em inglês ou é uma tradução de baixa qualidade do site SO?

---

#### In English:

Title: Mixture of English and Portugues on home page  https://pt.stackoverflow.com?

I just looked at the home page for Stack Overflow em Portugês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) from my browser, and see the welcome text:

> Stack Overflow em Português is a question and answer site for programadores profissionais e entusiastas. It only takes a minute to sign up.

and:

> Explore our Questions

which look like an odd mixture of English and Portuguese rather than pure Portuguese.

[image: What I see in Firefox Quantum 69.0.1 on a Mac running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave]

Is this just a problem because my browser is set to work in English, or is it a poor quality translation of the SO site?

Comment: Sugestões no traducir: https://pt.traducir.win/string/2697 e https://pt.traducir.win/string/11520, agora é só aguardas os revisores aprovarem e o sistema atualizar em seguida.

Comment: Traduções aprovadas, só aguardar um moderador encaminhá-las para o Transifex.